# Java SWT Height of shell Caption/Title bar

Tags: java, swt, metrics, titlebar

How do I determine the height of an application window's title bar in a Java SWT application application?

Since Java is platform agnostic, I need to find the Java way.

As a side question, is the title/caption bar height information in the same location as other system/window metrics?

I tried searching for "caption bar" and "title bar", just did not see anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to calculate the height difference between the "bounds" of your `Shell` and the "client area" of the `Shell`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Calculate");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            Rectangle outer = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell().getBounds();
            Rectangle inner = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell().getClientArea();

            System.out.println(outer.height - inner.height);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
            shell.getDisplay().sleep();
    }
}
```

Will print 31 (px) on my laptop running Linux Mint.

Comment: I will add that the result above returns the caption bar along with the height of the top and bottom border. The caption bar height would then be: cyCaptionBar = outer.height - inner.height - shell.getBorderWidth() * 2;